# SSIS Flat File Import into Oracle failing despite DT_WSTR definitions

Tags: oracle, unicode, ssis

I am getting error messages about being unable to convert between unicode and non-unicode character sets when trying to import a flat file via SSIS.

My flat file is UTf-8 encoded according to Notepad++.  The file contains characters such as the "microgram" character (µg) for example.

My flat file connection manager is set up to use 65001 (UTF8) and all my columns are set up on my flat file connection manager to be DT_WSTR, and the data previews OK in the flat file connection manager.

My database is Oracle 11g, using Microsoft Oracle OLEDB driver for Oracle.

I have tried VARCHAR2 and NVARCHAR dta types in Oracle, but when I connect my DT_WSTR (65001) columns to my Oracle tables, I get the unicode conversion error.

I have tried conversion steps in my SSIS packaged, to convert to DT_WSTR and DT_STR.  Had some success with DT_STR, but I got my microgram symbol scrambled.

How hard should this be?  I set up a 65001 text file connection, with DT_WSTR column types and I cannot for the life of me connect it to Oracle using VARCHAR2, NVARCHAR.

Any advice appreciated.

Stephen

Comment: Sometimes I find it easier to work with the data once it's already in SQL Server (or Oracle in your case) rather than try to figure out the magic in SSIS. If that's an option, go into the OLE Destination, select the connection manager, then select New table and go with their defaults instead of selecting an existing table from the drop down list.

Comment: I would suggest using a different OleDB driver - the oracle one is a lot better for handling the specific oracle column types